# Map requests to other directory with htaccess without redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have a project structure like this:

```
/php/
    rest.php
/public/
    index.html
    /src/
        /css
        /js
        /img
/src/
  /sql/
.htaccess
```

I think it would be pretty nice if only files in /public/ would be accessable via the web. I would like to access these files via **domain.tld/** instead of **domain.tld/public**. How can I map the requests from / to /public?

Tried something like this but it doesn't work!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!public/)` is negative lookahead to prevent infinite looping, that avoid forwarding to `/public/` if URI already starts with `/public/`.